# How to make regular-expression end at first chance. (Kotlin)

Tags: regex, kotlin

Say I have a string that contains a program with notes as follows:

```
var iString = "int i; //A variable \n" +
"//This is a text with notes \n" +
"//Can you remove them? \n" +
"cout<<i; //printing i \n"
```

I've created a regular expression that would recognize notes:

```
var notes1= ("/"+"(\\s)*"+"/"+"(\\w|[^\\w])*"+"\\n").toRegex()
```

Problem is when writing `var newString = iString.replace(notes1,"")`

I accept newString to be: `"int i; cout<<i \n"`

Instead, the result is: `"int i;"`

The regular expression 'devours' the whole string till the last `"\n"` while I wanted is to end whenever is gets the chance.

How do I define it in Kotlin?

Comment: `iString` uses "/n" instead of "\n". Is that intentional?

Comment: Wouldn't something like `//.*[\n]*` work?

Comment: @mfulton26 - No, it's a mistake. I've fixed it.

Comment: @I'L'I It's possible there's more than one space between the `"//"`.
As for the `".*"` for some reason it doesn't work in Kotlin.

Comment: @user3601872 could you please explain why you specified your question to relate to the "kotlin" topic? Kotlin (after Java and many other languages) support the regular expressions syntax which is standard and language-independent. How does knowing kotlin help answer this question?

Comment: @user3601872 Could you tell what are you trying to achieve in general? If you want to parse some C++ code, then regular expressions isn't a suitable tool for this task.

Comment: @user3601872 about the Kotlin tag - could you please remove the tag from your question and reformulate it so it is language-agnostic? Irrelevant tags  confuse others

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`X*` is a greedy quantifier (see [Quantifiers (The Java™ Tutorials > Essential Classes > Regular Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html)).

You can use `X*?` instead which is a reluctant quantifier:

```
var iString = "int i; //A variable \n" +
        "//This is a text with notes \n" +
        "//Can you remove them? \n" +
        "cout<<i; //printing i \n"
var notes1= ("/"+"(\\s)*"+"/"+"(\\w|[^\\w])*?"+"\\n").toRegex()
println(iString.replace(notes1, ""))
```

Output:

```
int i; cout<<i;
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you! 
Who doesn't love a one-line, let alone a one-character solution?